# Android OpenGL ES Texture Size Power of 2

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm already know that a lot of hardware needs textures with power of two sizes.But is squared image sizes compulsory?I mean 32x32 64x64 512x512.Can i use a texture with 512x256 size in every hardwares?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, texture can be non-square, that is no problem. As long as you keep width and height power of two.

Answer (score 1):

No, it must be a 2base. However, you can get around this by adding black bars to the top and/or bottom of your image, then using the texture coordinates array to restrict where the texture will be mapped from your image. For example, lets say you have a 13 x 16 pixel texture. You can add 3 pixels of black to the right side then do the following:

```
static const GLfloat texCoords[] = {
    0.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 13.0/16.0,
    1.0, 0.0,
    1.0, 13.0/16.0
};
```

so you can have any size now